# Hide ComboBox when opening a userform

Tags: vba

I have a ComboBox called ComboBox1 and I want it to be hidden when I open the userform. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the userform code or append to your `UserForm_Initialize`.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  ComboBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```